# how to add nil to nsmutablearray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, null

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ΕΛΤΑ",
                      @"ΕΛΤΑ COURIER", @"ACS", @"ACS ΕΞΩΤΕΡΙΚΟ", 
                      @"DHL", @"INTERATTICA", @"SPEEDEX", 
                      @"UPS", @"ΓΕΝΙΚΗ ΤΑΧΥΔΡΟΜΙΚΗ", @"ΜΕΤΑΦΟΡΙΚΕΣ ΕΞΩΤΕΡΙΚΟΥ", nil];
```

This is working because it has nil at the end.

But I add objects like this: `addObject:name` etc...
So at the end I have to add nil I do this addObhect:nil but when I run the app it still crashes at `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

how can I do this work?

Ok, I dont have to add nil

What is the reason that my app crashes then?

Comment: Since your app is apparently crashing while populating a UITableView, perhaps you should share the code for your implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath. Also more information regarding the "crash" your getting would help. Is it a SIG_ABORT, or an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, and is there an exception (check the console Shift+Apple+R in XCode).

Comment: When you add them "one at a time", you **do not have to add nil at the end**. Think of if this way, if it helps: when you are addin gthem "one at a time" then the nil is "already there", the system takes care of that.

Comment: I can't help but feel that mr-sk, mike-weller, and akosma's answers should be combined into the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't add nil when you're calling `addObject`.

Answer (score 234):

If you must add a `nil` object to a collection, use the `NSNull` class:

> The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow nil values).

Assuming "array" is of type NSMutableArray:

```
....
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
[array addObject:@"string"];
[array addObject:[NSNull null]];
```

Comment: for new folks (me), example of test to see if array element equals the inserted nil value, 'if ([self.voice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] != [NSNull null]) {'  (thank you akosma)

Answer (score 27):

You don't need to call `[addObject:nil]`

The `nil` in `initWithObjects:` is only there to tell the method where the list ends, because of how C `varargs` work. When you add objects one-by-one with `addObject:` you don't need to add a nil.

Comment: Also, the nil is called a "sentinel" because it "guards" the end of the list so that things don't iterate off of the end. It's worth knowing that it's called a sentinel because you may see a compiler error/warning like "missing sentinel value ...". In this case it means you forgot a nil at the end of something, usually a list after initWithObjects.

Comment: So basically if you are add using the ```addObjects``` method on a NSMutableArray, you don't need to add a ```nil``` at the end? It just knows when it reaches the end itself?

Answer (score 15):

If you really want a Null-ish item in your collection, [NSNull](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html) is there for that.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add [`NSNull`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/index.html) class and the best way to do it is like this:

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"string", @42, [NSNull null] ];
```

I personally recommend to use a specific value like `0` instead of null or nil in your design of your code, but sometimes you need to add null.

There is a good explanation from [this Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FoundationClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH9-SW1).

Answer (score 6):

nil is used to terminate the array

Answer (score 5):

`nil` is not an object that you can add to an array: An array cannot contain `nil`. This is why `addObject:nil` crashes.

Answer (score 2):

pass your object through this method when adding to array to avoid **attempt to insert nil object from objects** crashes.

```
-(id) returnNullIfNil:(id) obj  {
    return (obj == nil) ? ([NSNull null]) : (obj);
}
```

[NSNull null] returns an null object which represents nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an object to an `NSArray` because that class is immutable. You have to use `NSMutableArray` if you want to change the array after it is created.