# NSMutableArray: addObject "nil"?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am having troubling adding "nil" at the end of an array, I get "NSInvalidArgumentException" ?

```
NSMutableArray *k = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
    [k addObject: @"blank"];
}
[k addObject: nil]; //<-- NSInvalidArgumentException
```

I need to do all this item by item in a loop and then add the "nil".

Thanks

(I am then taking this array and initializing a 2D array.
The problem is that I can't successfully "replaceObjectAtIndex" with an array without "nil".
If I build the "k" with "initWithObjects: @"blank", @"blank", @"blank", ... nil" this will work.  However writing 1000 blanks is a little much. So that is the purpose of the loop.)

////// HERE IS THE TRIAL AND ERROR CODE for init and building 2D Matrix for the purpose of reading and storing a matrix from a "CSV file" //////

```
///*
NSMutableArray *ppp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

NSNull *myNull = [NSNull null];
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    //[kkk addObject: [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%d",i]];
    [kkk addObject: myNull];
}
//[kkk addObject: nil];

[ppp addObject:kkk];
[ppp addObject:kkk];
//*/


/*
// this is successful --> just uncomment this block and comment out the block above
[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             @"z1",
             @"z2",
             @"z3",
             @"z4",
             @"z5",
             @"z6",
             @"z0gg",
             @"z0hh",
             @"z0ii",
             @"z0jj",
             nil
             ]];

[ppp addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @"a1",
        @"b2",
        @"c3",
        @"d4",
        @"e5",
        @"f6",
        nil
        ]];
```

*/

```
[[ppp objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"HOTDOG"];
[[ppp objectAtIndex:1] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"HOHO"];
// HOHO will replace HOTDOG as well for the code not using "nil"
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [how to add nil to nsmutablearray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057910/how-to-add-nil-to-nsmutablearray)

Comment: In `initWithObjects`, nil won't be part of the array. Please check my answer.

Comment: You can have as many `NSNull` objects in your array as you want. An `NSNull` instance is just another object, as far as the mutable array is concerned.

Comment: If I build the "k" with "initWithObjects: @"blank", @"blank", @"blank", ... nil" this will work. (into the NSMutableArray)

Comment: Again: in `initWithObjects: @"blank", @"blank", @"blank", ... nil` nil is __not__ part of the array.

Comment: You might instead populate your array with `NSNull` references, instead of `NSString`s. If you have an array with 1000 blanks, then I think you'll get a smaller array that way.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of thing are you putting into this array when you use `-replaceObjectAtIndex:`? Maybe there's a better way to do this.

Comment: but for some reason "nil" makes all the difference in the world when I take this column and build a 2d matrix with it.  When I write to one item, all the "items" change to that "one item".  But if I use "nil" in the build of a column, I successfully write to only one "item."

Comment: Of course. If you write 10 literals, you'll have 10 different objects. If you add then in a loop, the 10 objects will point to the same literal. But I'll state again: in `initWithObjects: @"blank", @"blank", @"blank", ... nil` nil is **not** **not** **not** part of the array.

Comment: I am reading a CSV spreadsheet file and parsing the string into a matrix

Comment: again... I have done this using a NSMutableArray with and without "nil".  Not using "nil" fails!

Comment: @jdl: Yes, you must specify a nil as last argument, but that nil is only a marker value to indicate the end of the list, the nil is not stored in the array.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: Upvoting because I won't say that again :-)

Comment: @sidyll: LOL! I won't say it again either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot add `nil` to an `NSMutableArray`, and [you will raise an exception if you try to](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDEFAA).

There's `NSNull`, though:

```
NSNull *myNull = [NSNull null];
[myMutableArray addObject:myNull];
```

You might ask yourself why you're trying to do this, however.

Comment: Heh. You [beat me to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057910/how-to-add-nil-to-nsmutablearray/2058632#2058632).

Comment: I applied this, same problem as not adding "nil".  But the NSNull will be useful for other things

Comment: Perhaps you can post code for what's giving you problems, and we can try it out on the other end to see what's up.

Comment: The `-addObject:` method is a bit unclearly named. You're not adding a unique copy of the object to your array, you are adding a *reference* to the object (in ObjC-speak, you are increasing its retain count by one). And so when you change what's in the reference, it will change that for whatever references it. In other words, by doing this twice: `[ppp addObject:kkk];` you are adding two references of `kkk` to `ppp`. When you change `kkk` in `ppp`'s "first" object with the `-replaceObjectAtIndex:` method, this change affects what the "second" `kkk` holds (there's really only one `kkk`).

Comment: To verify this, you could add a mutable array called `kkk2` and construct and modify it similarly, after adding it to the `ppp` mutable array. Then see how it behaves. It should behave as if it is unique, because it is a separate object (and not as a second reference to the same object).

Comment: Just stated that in a comment at the same time. Thanks for clarifying it too Alex. Makes me feel better :-)

Comment: Thanks... Ok... bottom line I am trying to create space for a matrix. Using what you said, I then would have to create a loop for each column to create space to avoid the ref tied to many places. ??? Is there a simpler way ???

Answer (score 9):

You don't need a nil as the last element in an array.

Don't confuse yourself with variadic methods like `+arrayWithObjects:` which receive a flexible number of arguments, and then need to find which one was the last. That's because in those methods implementation (as well as in variadic C functions) you can't retrieve the number of arguments passed, so nil marks the end.

---

As a general rule, you can nest loops in the same amount as of your dimensions. In your case, this would populate a "2D" array with different objects:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
int i,j;

for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    NSMutableArray *s_array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:s_array];
    for (j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        [s_array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d", i, j]];
    }
}
```

Comment: @jdl: why exactly you can't replace an object in an array that's not nil terminated? I'm sure you can!

Comment: when I replace one item, for some reason all items are affected with the last "replace".

Comment: @jdl: your code shows clearly that in the first case, you're creating an array of 10 objects and then adding this array two times to the array `ppp`. So, `ppp` contains 2 sets of 10 objects. These 10 objects are **the same** in both arrays. The objects are not "copied", their references are copied. In the second case, you created different objects. More specifically, you created 2 sets of different objects. It's not related to whether nil was included or not. Again, the nil in `initWithObjects` **is not part of the array**.

Comment: Ok... bottom line I am trying to create space for a matrix.  Using what you said, I then would have to create a loop for each column to create space. ??? Is there a simpler way ??? thanks

Comment: +1 for a good explanation of the relationship of `nil` to variadic functions.

Comment: @jdl: Yes, but there's a simpler way. Thanks @Alex

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add nil .. ( and you dont have to ).

Comment: +1 for the concise and correct answer and also to help you with your 3k :-)