# Apple Review refuses NSBundle exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, md5

I try to publish app in App Store, but I got response from Apple team, that app crashes. I use Crashlytics so I got specific line of crash.
I wasn't able to duplicate crash - on device or in simulator.

This code should calculate md5 sum of static resources to make sure that nobody changed them.

Code:

```
NSArray *formats = @[@"html", @"mustache", @"strings", @"p12", @"xml", @"der", @"nss", @"css", @"json", @"plist"];
NSArray *filesToSkip = @[@"Info.plist"];

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *resourcePath = [bundle resourcePath];
NSFileManager *man = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *resPaths = [man subpathsAtPath:resourcePath];
resPaths = [resPaths sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *sums = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *path in resPaths) {
    if([filesToSkip containsObject:[path lastPathComponent]] == NO && [formats containsObject:[path pathExtension]]) {
        NSString *fullPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
        NSData *content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        NSString *md5 = [content md5];

        [sums addObject:md5]; //line of crash - inserting nil element into the NSMutableArray
    }
}
```

`md5` method if from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16391701/5226328 - returns nil when NSData object is nil.

It tried to find problem, but I have no idea what is going on:

I can't find any scenario that would make `md5` (string) nil (even with bundle == nil or resourcePath == nil it shouldn't crash in that line).

I guess I miss something (or don't understand Apple Review methods). Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add nil into an NSMutableArray using the method addObject. Alternatively you could try to add [NSNull null] to the array anytime the MD5 method returns nil. Later on in the code when you use the NSMutableArray you will also need to check it for the NSNull objects and interpret them as nil.

Here's a similar post:[how to add nil to nsmutablearray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057910/how-to-add-nil-to-nsmutablearray)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know I can't add nil to NSMutableArray. But provided code shouldn't ever try this. To add nil `resurcePath` or `path` would have to be nil - but then for-in wouldn't be executed. Another possibility - `fullPath` doesn't point to any file. But it also unlikely - paths are obtained few lines earlier.
I know that it can't be nil. But I don't know how it's possible that it is nil.